# What is the best way to provide transaction operation if I use graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

If I need to mutate multiple variables as part of a transaction, what is the best approach?

As far as I understand, grapQL will issue individual mutation command sequently behind the scene. What I need to do to make it transactional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this a single mutation that performs multiple DB operations? If so, your mutation resolver is expected to perform all the operations, so it can manage the transaction itself: open, perform multiple operations, close.

If you're performing multiple mutations in a single request, they're always executed serially. In this case, you can simply open the transaction when you start GraphQL processing (e.g. in the controller or servlet or an instrumentation) and close it once you receive the result (or an exception). So the transaction management is *around* GraphQL execution, but outside of it.

If you want only certain operations from the request to be executed transactionally but not the others, you're already in the territory best left to frameworks. Use something like Spring's transaction management and let that deal with the correct lifecycle.

If you're, on the other hand, trying to implement a transaction spanning multiple distinct requests, this is really not something you should be doing, for many reasons, extremely convoluted transaction management being only one.